# DropDownList losing value on databind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following DropDownList

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStartMonth" runat="server" />
```

And I'm setting the DataSource as follows:

```
    ListItemCollection items = new ListItemCollection();
    items.Add(new ListItem("January", "1"));
    items.Add(new ListItem("February", "2"));
    items.Add(new ListItem("March", "3"));
    items.Add(new ListItem("April", "4"));
    items.Add(new ListItem("May", "5"));
    items.Add(new ListItem("June", "6"));
    items.Add(new ListItem("July", "7"));
    items.Add(new ListItem("August", "8"));
    items.Add(new ListItem("September", "9"));
    items.Add(new ListItem("October", "10"));
    items.Add(new ListItem("November", "11"));
    items.Add(new ListItem("December", "12"));

    ddlStartMonth.DataSource = items;
    ddlStartMonth.DataBind();
```

As soon as I call `DataBind()`, each item's value is overwritten by its text value (e.g. the text-value pair ("January", "1") becomes ("January", "January"). So, if I were to do something like

```
int month = 1;
ddlStartMonth.SelectedValue = month.ToString();
```

"January" would be the selected item in the DropDownList, but instead, the operation is ignored, and the DropDownList maintains the previously selected value. I must be missing something here... Any ideas?

**Note**: These values need to be created programmatically.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try setting the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties:

```
ListItemCollection items = new ListItemCollection();
items.Add(new ListItem("January", "1"));
items.Add(new ListItem("February", "2"));
items.Add(new ListItem("March", "3"));
items.Add(new ListItem("April", "4"));
items.Add(new ListItem("May", "5"));
items.Add(new ListItem("June", "6"));
items.Add(new ListItem("July", "7"));
items.Add(new ListItem("August", "8"));
items.Add(new ListItem("September", "9"));
items.Add(new ListItem("October", "10"));
items.Add(new ListItem("November", "11"));
items.Add(new ListItem("December", "12"));

ddlStartMonth.DataSource = items;
ddlStartMonth.DataTextField = "Text";
ddlStartMonth.DataValueField = "Value";
ddlStartMonth.DataBind();
```

Or you can set them declaratively as well:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStartMonth" DataTextField="Text" DataValueField="Value" runat="server" /
```

Comment: I don't have an object, so I don't have any key or value names to assign to those properties. You would think the DropDownList would map those properties to the ListItem's text and value fields by default.

Comment: See edits, you'd use the Text and Value properties on the ListItem class objects you're binding to.

Comment: +1 for @KodeKreachor. Just set Text and Value properties as DataTextField and DataValueField. If you don't set those properties the ToString() method gets called on each item of the datasource object.

Comment: Plus one for the declarative syntax.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create the ddlStartMonth item list each time each time the page cycles (i.e., initial load as well as postbacks).

The correct place to do this is in OnInit() -- not PageLoad() -- As this prevents putting all of this data into Viewstate

Comment: This doesn't explain why my dropdownlists are being populated correctly, but my ListItem values are being overwritten. FYI. I did move my code to Page_Init with no noticeable difference.

Comment: I have to assume it it because you have these values coded in the .aspx or suchlike -- nothing happens magically, this list does not change unless you are doing something that changes it. -- nothing you posted relates to that problem.

Comment: Correction, nothing happens magically if you're working in a low-level language. When working with a framework, you're developing on top of other people's work. Other people, who determined the default behavior for the components in the framework. Which means that there could very well be unexpected behavior under certain circumstances.

Comment: Just because you are ignorant of what happens does not mean it is magic. Allowing default behavior IS "doing something" just like failing to pay your taxes is doing something -- there is no default behavior that rebinds the listitems as the OP describes. It looks like he is calling AddItem without setting independent value and text, but no way to tell from what is posted.

Comment: As @KodeKreachor stated, if you don't set the DataTextField and DataValueVield properties, the ToString() method gets called on each item of the datasource object. I can't be the only person who finds this odd. When working with a control that expects a ListItemCollection object, it would make more sense for the control to bind its text and value properties to the corresponding ListItem text and value properties without having to specify the ListItem text and value attributes on the front-end. But I guess that's just my opinion.